# Spacewalk client OSAD service SSL error

Tags: centos, ssl, xmpp, rhn, spacewalk

I have some problems with my freshly Spacewalk setup.

I have registered my test client, and installed osad service to avoid executing rhn_check.

But when I start osad service, I get the following error:

```
Starting osad: Not able to reconnect
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/rhn/osad/jabber_lib.py", line 253, in setup_connection
c = self._get_jabber_client(js)
File "/usr/share/rhn/osad/jabber_lib.py", line 320, in _get_jabber_client
c.connect()
File "/usr/share/rhn/osad/jabber_lib.py", line 604, in connect
raise SSLDisabledError
SSLDisabledError
[  OK  ]
```

I try to start osad with command `osad -v` and I get the following:

```
2014-11-06 11:26:23 jabber_lib.__init__:
2014-11-06 11:26:23 jabber_lib.connect: Server did not return a <features /> stanza, reconnecting
2014-11-06 11:26:24 jabber_lib.connect: Server did not return a <features /> stanza, reconnecting
2014-11-06 11:26:25 jabber_lib.connect: Server did not return a <features /> stanza, reconnecting
Not able to reconnect
2014-11-06 11:26:26 jabber_lib.print_message: SSLError
2014-11-06 11:26:26 jabber_lib.print_message: Could not connect to jabber server spacewalk.example.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/rhn/osad/jabber_lib.py", line 253, in setup_connection
c = self._get_jabber_client(js)
File "/usr/share/rhn/osad/jabber_lib.py", line 320, in _get_jabber_client
c.connect()
File "/usr/share/rhn/osad/jabber_lib.py", line 604, in connect
raise SSLDisabledError
SSLDisabledError

2014-11-06 11:26:26 jabber_lib.setup_connection: Could not connect to any jabber server
```

Spacewalk server have jabberd and osa-dispatcher running properly, and listening on port 5222/TCP

Also, I'm able to connect to Spacewalk's port 5222 via telnet from client machine.

Both machines have iptables disabled and SELinux in permissive mode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I increased debug verbosity and I saw the SSL certificate CN didn't match the Satellite server's FQDN.

Seems that SSL cert was not properly created at Spacewalk server setup